# Removing items from localStorage using the setTimeout() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage, settimeout

The `userData` item in localStorage maps to JSON string passed from the server.
What I want to do is remove this item from localStorage everytime the PHP session ends and set the userId to default.

variables.js

```
var userIdDefault = 1;
var sessionDuration = 1440;

if(localStorage.getItem('userData')) {
    var userDataStored = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData'));
    var userId = userDataStored["userId"];

    var sessionStartTime = parseInt(userDataStored["sessionStartTime"]);
    var sessionStopTime = sessionStartTime + sessionDuration;
}
else {
    var userId = userIdDefault;
}
```

main.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(userDataStored) {
        var timeNow = Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
        waitTime = sessionStopTime - timeNow;

        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('sessionStartTime: ' + sessionStartTime);
            console.log('waitTime: ' + waitTime);
            console.log('timeNow: ' + timeNow);
            console.log('sessionStopTime: ' + sessionStopTime);
        
            localStorage.removeItem("userId");
            var userId = userIdDefault;
        }, waitTime); 
    }
});
```

Browser console logs:

> 1st page reload
> main.js: sessionStartTime: 1422232761
> main.js: waitTime: 1434
> main.js: timeNow: 1422232767
> main.js: sessionStopTime: 1422234201
>
> 2nd page reload
> main.js: sessionStartTime: 1422232761
> main.js: waitTime: 1416
> main.js: timeNow: 1422232785
> main.js: sessionStopTime: 1422234201
>
> userDataStored
> Object {userId: "23", login: "login2", firstName: "name", lastName: "name", email: "example@mail.com"...}
>
> userId
> "23"

Comment: I can't use sessionStorage because it stores data only when the browser window is open. I need the data to be stored until the PHP session stops.

Comment: PHP session and local browser are no way connected...You would need to code some sort of check when the page loads....

Comment: That's why I included an Unix Epoch timestamp of when the PHP session started in the JSON string - sessionStartTime. PHP sessions last for 1440 seconds (20 minutes) - sessionDuration. So if add these two, I get the time the PHP session ends - sessionStopTime. Then I compare it to the actual time.    I don't know if I'm using setTimeout() in the right way.

Comment: And when the browser closes before the timer fires?

Comment: Although this won't work after the browser was closed, I don't why it doesn't work when it's still open. The waitTime counts down everytime the page reloads, but when it reaches 0, neither does it remove the userData item, nor does it set the userId  to the default value.

Comment: I believe your `userId` is out of scope in the setTimeout function.  Try getting rid of the `var` before it or, better yet, making it part of an object and passing it as a parameter to the timeout function.  I'm not sure about the localStorage.  I would also try passing the window object explicitly to the timeout function and see if calling the localStorage on the passed object works better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code does not work because there is no data in the localstorage with the key 
userId. User Id is a key in a JSON object you have stored in localstorage.

```
var userDataStored = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData'));
userDataStored.userId = null;
localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(userDataStored ));
```